# How to draw heart using HTML/CSS table?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-tables

I'm trying to draw heart:

[image]

using HTML table's nth-child property, but can't figure out how to do it: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaPpQB)

```
table tr td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+7) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really only want to use the 'nth-child' then use the following:

First row:

```
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3),
table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

So, in your table, the first tr followed by the 3rd and 5th td should have red background. Apply the same logic for all the following rows.

For the second row you could use the nth-last-child too:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+4) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

The whole solution then comes out like this:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4),
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6),
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3),
table tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3),
table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(n+4),
table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(n+5) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

If you were looking for a formula that describes a heart shape, then you could start here for example:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

But implementing such a formula is out of scope of CSS I think.

Comment: thanks, followed you instructions, and got this result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaPpQB

Comment: You can also write it up as only one CSS rule, like how I updated it in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

you could use box shadows!

```css
div{
  height:200px;width:200px;
  background:lightgray;
  position:relative;  
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;top:left:0;height:40px;width:40px;
  background:transparent;
  box-shadow:
    
    40px 0 tomato,                                     120px 0 tomato,
    0 40px tomato, 40px 40px tomato, 80px 40px tomato, 120px 40px tomato,160px 40px tomato,
    
    0 80px tomato, 40px 80px tomato, 80px 80px tomato, 120px 80px tomato,160px 80px tomato,
    
    
    
                   40px 120px tomato, 80px 120px tomato, 120px 120px tomato,
                          80px 160px tomato
    
  ;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need only HTML table's nth-child property

Comment: tomato tomato tomato tomato